# How to escape a colon in .gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I have a line like this:

```yaml
sed -i 's/"host: TND_HOST"/"host: process.env.TND_HOST"/g' services/management/tnd.js
```

and the option above causes linting error:

```
This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line [...]
```

Other options that do not work are:

```yaml
sed -i 's/host: TND_HOST/host: process.env.TND_HOST/g' services/management/tnd.js

sed -i "s/host: TND_HOST/host: process.env.TND_HOST/g" services/management/tnd.js
```

Any way to overcome the issue and keep it as a one-liner?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Since you are using both types of quotes it is probably easiest to put your command in a yaml template. That way you don't need to escape anything:

```
stages:
  - lint

.sed_template: &sed_template |
 sed -i 's/"host: TND_HOST"/"host: process.env.TND_HOST"/g' services/management/tnd.js

some_job:
  image: someImage:latest
  stage: lint
  except:
    - master
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
      - frontend/node_modules/
  script:
    - echo "firstLine"
    - *sed_template
    - echo "lastLine"
```

It's not quite a one liner anymore but I guess its the cleanest option as it keeps the command itself rather readable.
Another option would be using [folding style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2796251) which shrinks it down a bit:

```
stages:
  - lint

some_job:
  image: someImage:latest
  stage: lint
  except:
    - master
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
      - frontend/node_modules/
  script:
    - echo "firstLine"
    - >
        sed -i 's/"host: TND_HOST"/"host: process.env.TND_HOST"/g' services/management/tnd.js
    - echo "lastLine"
```

Comment: The second option looks a bit more clear and I used it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 13):

You do not have to formally escape colons. See the examples below.

One approach is to put your command's argument with colons wrapped in single quotes into a variable. You can use variables inside your argument string.

Then `eval` that "stringified' command with the variables like the following (the example is for `curl` to trigger external deployment, but should work for every command):

```yaml
deploy_job:
  variables:
    DEPLOY_CURL_COMMAND: 'curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $DO_APP_PLATFORM_API_TOKEN" https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/apps/$DO_APP_PLATFORM_STAGE_FRONT_APP_ID/deployments'
  script:
    - echo "Stage Deploy to DigitalOcean App Platform"
    - echo $DEPLOY_CURL_COMMAND
    - 'eval "$DEPLOY_CURL_COMMAND"'
```

There are also some other ways to avoid `:`  (colon followed by space) issue:

```bash
  script:
    # 1. Note how the single quotes eliminate colon+space issue.
    - 'MESSAGE="Tests finished with status: ${CI_JOB_STATUS}"'
    # 2. Here pipe operator allows using colon+space on the next line.
    - |
      curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data "{\"text\":\"$MESSAGE\"}" "$SOME_URL"
    # 3. Here we refrain from using pipe operator and instead wrap the entire command in sigle quotes as in 1. 
    # Note that I replaced single with double quotes on HTTP header.
    - 'curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" --data "{\"text\":\"$MESSAGE\"}" "$SOME_URL"'
```

Be very precise with all the quotes, dashes and spaces along the script. YAML is quite unforgiving. Check the syntax with GitLab pipeline [editor and linter](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/lint.html). Actually it is much quicker to develop your pipeline in the editor first.

If you use the project / repository level [variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) do not forget to uncheck `protected` checkbox (checked by default) when setting a variable and using it in unprotected branch (which is a branch default state).