# Unable to escape colon in Gitab CI/CD yaml

Tags: powershell, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

When I attempt to escape my yaml which contains a colon like so:

```
  script:
    - '${Env:TEMP}/${Env:VAR_VS_VERSION}.exe --layout c:/layout/${Env:VAR_VS_VERSION} --lang en-US --useLatestInstaller --cache --fix --wait --norestart'
```

I get the following error:

```
ParserError: 
Line |
 308 |  ${Env:TEMP}/${Env:VAR_VS_VERSION}.exe --layout c:/layout/${Env:VAR_VS .
     |                                          ~~~~~~
     | Unexpected token 'layout' in expression or statement.
ParserError: 
Line |
   1 |  }
     |  ~
     | Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
```

The CI linter is saying everything is valid and the other questions/answers on Stack Overflow don't seem to help.

- I've tried single and double quotes around my entire command, doesn't work
- I've tried folding style from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68085350/2502089), doesn't work

Any suggestions?

Comment: use ```\``` to escape

Comment: That doesn't work and I still get the error

Comment: GitLab and Yaml are incidental to your problem; in PowerShell, an executable path that is _quoted_ or contains _variable references_ (such as in your case) must - for syntactic reasons - be invoked with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-); see the linked duplicate for details. In short (all on one line): `- '& ${Env:TEMP}/${Env:VAR_VS_VERSION}.exe --layout c:/layout/${Env:VAR_VS_VERSION} --lang en-US --useLatestInstaller --cache --fix --wait --norestart'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script string from your YAML is being interpreted as intended, the problem is the powershell syntax is wrong.

The part `${Env:TEMP}/${Env:VAR_VS_VERSION}.exe` is not valid for calling an executable. In powershell, this is interpreted as **division**, not string concatenation. However, before powershell attempts to do the division, it validates the entire command string -- because a flag like `--token` doesn't make sense after a division call, it throws a `ParserError`. If you remove all the text after `.exe` you will probably see a `RuntimeException` that makes this more clear.

Similarly, another example that demonstrates the same problem you have:

```
1/1 --foo
```

Will produce:

```
At line:1 char:7
+ 1/1 --foo
+       ~~~
Unexpected token 'foo' in expression or statement.
```

To fix your issue, you need to fix your powershell syntax to be valid. What you probably want to do is use the call operator (`&`) to call your executable:

```yaml
script:
  - '& ${Env:TEMP}\${Env:VAR_VS_VERSION}.exe --layout c:/layout/${Env:VAR_VS_VERSION} --lang en-US --useLatestInstaller --cache --fix --wait --norestart'
```